# FreeForm not allowing file upload fields to be required

Tags: solspace-freeform

A site I'm working on is **EE 2.5.5** with **Freeform 4.0.10**.

There are several required fields already, but I'm trying to add two file upload fields to be required as well. I've had no luck yet with adding the field short name to the required part of the form tag.

```
{exp:freeform:form
    allowed_file_types="doc|docx|pdf"
    form_name="{embed:form_name}"
    form:class="form new-hire-form"
    form:id="new-hire-form"
    required="first_name|last_name|address_1|city|state|postal_code|how_hear_about_us|email_address|phone_number|cover_letter|resumes"
    return="{embed:return}"
}
```

and the way the tag is being called inside this is

```
{freeform:field:cover_letter}
```

I've also tried adding a hidden field per another devs request, but that didn't help at all either.

Any suggestions or pointers on what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall having trouble with FreeForm uploads a while back...

Latest version for EE2 is [4.2.5](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/) would definitely recommend you update and see if your problems are resolved.